# Thin lens equation calculation does not match experimental value, why?

Tags: experimental-physics, geometric-optics, home-experiment

for an optics experiment I had to design a $2$-lens system to image a grating, the diagram looks like this:
[image]

The focal length of both lenses is $15$cm, at the end of the system there's a camera connected to a computer where the image is displayed. The system should have magnification $M=1$. I followed the thin lens equation, and placed the first lens $30$cm away from the grating, an aperture $30$cm from the first lens (this is the intermediate image plane) then the second lens 30cm from the aperture and finally the camera $30$cm to the right of the second lens. The strange thing is that it didn't work, I had to place the camera $22.3$cm from the second lens in order to get a sharp image, I don't understand why this happens whether the aperture is doing something that I'm not understanding or if the thin lens approximation is breaking down. Does anyone have a suggestion? I don't think it's the aperture because the radius was large compared to the wavelength of the laser, and the aperture was only used to select different areas on the grating that corresponded to different spacings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the camera, and replace it with a piece of paper. You should see the sharp image as predicted by the thin lens equation.

If you use a camera, you are adding another lens, and the image forms behind the lens on the sensor. That is fine, but you have to do more calculating to figure out where to put the lens and sensor.

Perhaps you want to take a picture of the paper instead of using the camera as part of the system?

Comment: Hi, ok so technically I placed the actual sensor of the camera 30cm from the lens but you are right I didn't take into account the lens in the camera. So that is probably what happens. It would be nice to do the piece of paper test but I can't go back to the lab (virus) Thanks for the answer! (I upvoted but it's not displayed because I'm too low ranked on this stack exchange)